# AWS Step Functions Map State and how to fetch more records into it once it finishes looping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am building a step function that reads e.g. ~200 records from a DB with a lambda (let's call it "FetchBatch") and then calls a map state which iterates over every record and calls another lambda to do the processing.

As soon as the loop finishes, I would like to recall the "FetchBatch" lambda passing in the last record processed index, to fetch the next 200 records and so on, until all the records have been fetched/processed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer this. What seems to be the correct way is to handle this in a stateless manner, create as many batches as I want (via a query returning the start_index and end_index of each batch as output) and have the mapstate iterate of this dataset and call a lambda to handle each batch. Can even run these batches in a parallel manner, mapstate allows you to control this via maximum  concurrency property